# How to create a bar plot with 2 columns containing sum of 0s and 1s?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I'm trying to do a barplot very simple using ggplot2 package but I fail.
I'm trying to have 2 columns, one for each treatment. This will be my x axis. Then I would like to have the number of individuals that have learned in one colour and the number of individuals that have not learned in another one. The sum of all these individuals would be my y axis. And icing on the cake would be to add numbers of individuals that have learned and not learned on each part of each column.

So this is my dataset:

```
DataY
   Treatment Flock       ID Nb.participating Nb.above  Nb.ind Learned
1       Long    F2    bl4w4                6        4       0      No
2       Long    F2   g58b58                4        4       1     Yes
3       Long    F2  gy10cy8                5        2       0      No
4       Long    F2  p193y17                6        6       1     Yes
5       Long    F2   pu13g9                4        3       0      No
6       Long    F4   g57b57                6        6       1     Yes
7       Long    F4   g64b64                6        6       1     Yes
8       Long    F4  p149y89                4        3       0      No
9       Long    F4  p191y15                6        6       1     Yes
10      Long    F6 br73bl79                6        6       1     Yes
11      Long    F6 br91bl19                6        6       1     Yes
12      Long    F6  gy11cy9                6        6       1     Yes
13      Long    F6  p186y27                6        6       1     Yes
14      Long    F6   r68y48                6        6       1     Yes
15      Long    F8   g61b61                6        6       1     Yes
16      Long    F8   pu4756                5        5       1     Yes
17      Long    F8  pu66g66                4        1       0      No
18      Long    F8   r20y40                5        5       1     Yes
19      Long    F8   r66y46                6        6       1     Yes
20     Quick    F1  bl19r33                6        6       1     Yes
21     Quick    F1   g54b54                4        3       0      No
22     Quick    F1   gy2cy2                6        6       1     Yes
23     Quick    F1    pu4g4                6        6       1     Yes
25     Quick    F3  b25p163                5        5       1     Yes
26     Quick    F3   bl11r1                4        4       1     Yes
27     Quick    F3   g52b52                4        3       0      No
28     Quick    F3 gy13cy11                6        6       1     Yes
29     Quick    F3   pu9y49                5        3       0      No
30     Quick    F5   bl2r36                5        3       0      No
31     Quick    F5 br74bl80                6        2       0      No
32     Quick    F5   g53b53                5        5       1     Yes
33     Quick    F5  p167y47                6        6       1     Yes
34     Quick    F5  w64o162                6        6       1     Yes
35     Quick    F7   g63b63                5        4       0      No
36     Quick    F7  p141y86                5        5       1     Yes
37     Quick    F7  p184y25                6        5       0      No
38     Quick    F7  pu16y33                5        3       0      No
39     Quick    F7  y38gy61                5        4       0      No
```

This is my code:

```
ggplot(DataY, aes(x = Treatment, y = Nb.ind, fill = Learned)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

And my ugly barplot

[image: And my ugly barplot]

I tried to get around the problem replacing `0` in `Nb.ind` by `0.9`. I don't like this method but I didn't have any other idea. See my new dataset:

```
DataY
   Treatment Flock       ID Nb.participating Nb.above  Nb.ind Learned
1       Long    F2    bl4w4                6        4       0.9    No
2       Long    F2   g58b58                4        4       1     Yes
3       Long    F2  gy10cy8                5        2       0.9    No
4       Long    F2  p193y17                6        6       1     Yes
5       Long    F2   pu13g9                4        3       0.9    No
6       Long    F4   g57b57                6        6       1     Yes
7       Long    F4   g64b64                6        6       1     Yes
8       Long    F4  p149y89                4        3       0.9    No
9       Long    F4  p191y15                6        6       1     Yes
10      Long    F6 br73bl79                6        6       1     Yes
11      Long    F6 br91bl19                6        6       1     Yes
12      Long    F6  gy11cy9                6        6       1     Yes
13      Long    F6  p186y27                6        6       1     Yes
14      Long    F6   r68y48                6        6       1     Yes
15      Long    F8   g61b61                6        6       1     Yes
16      Long    F8   pu4756                5        5       1     Yes
17      Long    F8  pu66g66                4        1       0.9    No
18      Long    F8   r20y40                5        5       1     Yes
19      Long    F8   r66y46                6        6       1     Yes
20     Quick    F1  bl19r33                6        6       1     Yes
21     Quick    F1   g54b54                4        3       0.9    No
22     Quick    F1   gy2cy2                6        6       1     Yes
23     Quick    F1    pu4g4                6        6       1     Yes
25     Quick    F3  b25p163                5        5       1     Yes
26     Quick    F3   bl11r1                4        4       1     Yes
27     Quick    F3   g52b52                4        3       0.9    No
28     Quick    F3 gy13cy11                6        6       1     Yes
29     Quick    F3   pu9y49                5        3       0.9    No
30     Quick    F5   bl2r36                5        3       0.9    No
31     Quick    F5 br74bl80                6        2       0.9    No
32     Quick    F5   g53b53                5        5       1     Yes
33     Quick    F5  p167y47                6        6       1     Yes
34     Quick    F5  w64o162                6        6       1     Yes
35     Quick    F7   g63b63                5        4       0.9    No
36     Quick    F7  p141y86                5        5       1     Yes
37     Quick    F7  p184y25                6        5       0.9    No
38     Quick    F7  pu16y33                5        3       0.9    No
39     Quick    F7  y38gy61                5        4       0.9    No
```

But now I've got the colours separated by `ID`, I mean the column is like a list of the `ID` of each `Treatment` instead of being a sum of `Yes` (a block of green) and a sum of `No` (a block of red) on the top.

Closer to what I am looking for...

[image: Closer to what I am looking for...]

Any help would be very appreciated! Thanks :)

Comment: It looks like you want `ggplot(DataY, aes(x = Treatment, fill = Learned)) + geom_bar()`. You don't want `stat="identity"` or a `y` aesthetic, because you want `geom_bar`  to count the number of rows for each treatment. In addition, by setting `fill=Learned`, `geom_bar` will count the `Yes` and `No` values separately and use different colors for each each. You don't need to use `Nb.ind` at all, as the information is contains is redundant.

Comment: @eipi10 Thank you so much!! And may I ask you one more question? How can I add the numbers of individuals that have learned or not in each column? My code doesn't work: 
`ggplot(DataY, aes(x = Treatment, fill = Learned)) + 
  geom_bar() + 
  stat_count(aes(label = Nb.ind),
             geom = "text", 
             colour = "white", 
             size = 4, 
             position = position_dodge(width = 1))`

Comment: In the code below, the first call to `stat_count` counts the total number of rows for each level of `Treatment`. The second call to `stat_count` counts the number of rows for each level of `Learned` within each level of `Treatment`. Once again, you don't need `Nb.ind`, because `stat_count` isn't adding numbers; it's counting rows: `ggplot(DataY, aes(x = Treatment)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill = Learned)) +
  stat_count(geom="text", aes(label=..count..)) +
  stat_count(geom="text", aes(label=..count.., group=Learned), 
             position=position_stack(vjust=0.5))`

Comment: @eipi10 Thank you so much, you really saved me! I'm going to take a closer look at it :)